# Testing model validation without testing implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, validation

What's the best way of going about testing model validation without making assumptions on the implementation details of the validation (eg. DataAnnotations).

For example, if I have a `Customer` model object that has a `Firstname` property, I want to test *that* binding a missing value for the `Firstname` property will result in a validation error but I don't want to test *how* validation his been implemented. That is, I don't want to use `DataAnotations.Validate`.

I've seen several, differing, opinions on this floating around and haven't found one that I agree with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a helper method that wraps `ModelValidator` and returns `IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult>`. It requires that MVC be configured with your validation provider of choice, but it means that test code need not change when your validation implementation does:

```
public static IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate<TModel>(TModel model)
{
    var modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(r => r,
        new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(model));

    ModelValidator validator = ModelValidator.GetModelValidator(
        modelMetadata, new ControllerContext());

    return validator.Validate(model);
}
```

Comment: And what about the mvc configuration in a test project ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the framework you are using for validating your models. So what you are asking is not possible without taking this into account. ASP.NET MVC by default uses a data annotations model provider which invokes the validation rules for data annotations and if you want to test this you will need to do a `DataAnnotations.Validate` in your unit tests or verify that your model is decorated with the proper attributes.

Personally I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which provides an elegant way for [unit testing my validators](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) so it is not much of a hassle.

Comment: Couldn't the tests use the same abstraction that MVC uses?